# Oral Presentation Prize at a Conference

Tags: advisor, etiquette, awards

Abstract was selected for 'oral abstracts' competition, in a shortlist of 5 presenters. I was announced winner at the end of the competition. Following the event I have been emailed to pass on my bank details as the beneficiary of the £1500 prize. My co-authors are all seniors/co-supervisors. What should I do? Should I email them all to discuss splitting up the share? Or should I not raise the matter at all, to avoid embarrassment. From reading responses to a similar post before, I get the impression that since the award is for best Oral Presentation, and I am the only 'student' it should probably just go to me. At the same time, I don't want to just keep it without mentioning it to anybody.

Comment: Can you give more details on the competition?

Comment: Where is the embarrassment in winning a prize?

Comment: See [Share prize money from conference presentation award with co-authors?](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/58768/share-prize-money-from-conference-presentation-award-with-co-authors)

Comment: hi - no embarrassment in winning. they are aware i won and very happy. i just don't fancy talking about splitting cash with my seniors. to them it is probably negligible. to me, it is significant!

Comment: "I have been emailed to pass on my bank details" I would not suggest sending your bank account information by email.

Answer (score 3):

**You should absolutely inform your co-authors**

These people care about your career. They will be your recommenders, they will help you find jobs. People will ask them about your work. "Hey, I just won a big prize" is something I'd want to know if it was one of my students or postdocs - because I'd proceed to cheerfully show off the awesome work people in my lab are doing.

You can broach the subject of splitting the prize with them, but personally you did the presentation, and you won the award. If I was on the paper, I'd settle for a warm fuzzy feeling.

Comment: Thanks for replying  - I informed them about the winning. And they were all thrilled. But I did not know about any money attached to the presenter award..... so I just don't want to reopen an awkward conversation about money. i think for them the monetary side would be negligible, given their seniority. my one concern is whether somebody  suggests the money goes to a research 'fund' for our department. If that happened, I would be miffed!

Comment: This answer is great. As for sharing the prize: The money is yours and although it is very nice of you to consider to share it, I do not think that is necessary or expected. Maybe you could take your co-authors dinner or to a bar or something.

Comment: thanks louic - i probably agree with your sentiments the most!

Answer (score 0):

Congratulations! It will not hurt to let your co-authors know about the prize, and you can certainly offer to share the amount as well. As a student and presumably the only presenter, you are the primary recipient of this award, but your supervisors will likely be glad to know you received a substantial award.

Comment: Hi - thanks for replying! I didnt actually know about the cash award until a few days later. I did straightaway inform my supervisors that I had won and they were all delighted. They all congratulated me instantly. But I did not know or mention anything about cash awards at the time.